# Do we need $M$ simply connected for $H^*(E)=H^*(M)\otimes H^*(F)$ for $E$ a fibre bundle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, spectral-sequences, de-rham-cohomology

I'm following notations from sec. 14 Bott and Tu here:

Suppose $\pi :E\rightarrow M$ be a fibre bundle on a manifold with fibre $F$ and $\mathcal{U}=\{U_\alpha\}_\alpha$ be a good cover of $M$. Then consider the spectral sequence for the deRham-Cech double complex for $E$ w.r.t to the open cover $\{\pi^{-1}U_\alpha\}$. It has $E_1$ terms :

$E_1^{p,q}=\mathcal{C}^p(\mathcal{U},\mathscr{H}^q)$

where $\mathscr{H}^q$ is the presheaf w.r.t. $\mathcal{U}$ that assigns $H^q(\pi^{-1}U)$ to $U$.

Now this is a locally constant sheaf as $H^q(\pi^{-1}U)$ is isomorphic to $H^q(F)$. At this stage Bott and Tu say that this becomes a constant sheaf if $M$ is simply connected and so we'd have $H^*(E)=H^*(M)\otimes H^*(F)$ as vector spaces.

Now my question is : Isn't it possible to take a good cover of $M$ that is also a trivializing cover for $E$? Because if that was possible, our presheaf $\mathscr{H}^q$ would would become a constant sheaf right away and we'd have $H^*(E)=H^*(M)\otimes H^*(F)$ without $M$ having to be simply connected.

Can someone please clarify this ?

Comment: Are you sure your question is not asking if simply connectedness is required for the $E_2$ page to be $H^*(M) \otimes H^*(F)$? It is certainly not true for arbitrary bundles over simply connected $M$ that the cohomology has that form.

Comment: If $M$ is a simple connected smooth manifold and $E$ is a smooth fibre bundle , $E_2$ has that form, right?

Comment: you may be interested in the leray-hirsch theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Consider the Klein bottle $S$ as an $S^1$-bundle over $S^1$.

If the formula was correct then we would have $b_{2}(S) =1$, but it is non-orientable so $b_{2}(S) =0$.

There are orientable examples as well, also given by torus bundles over the torus. I think the strongest possible result due to Serre when this kind of multiplicity occurs was that the fundamental group acts in a certain way on the fibre, which is clearly true when the base is simply connected. In general the strongest possible technique to compute the homology is the Serre sprectral sequence.

Comment: thanks for the counterexample. Actually a trivialization is a diffeomorphism and so would give isomorphisms on the cohomology groups. In general it wouldn't be the identity map and so the locally constant presheaf I mentioned wouldn't become a constant presheaf.